# Can't get Real Path between two points

Tags: android, routes, openstreetmap, osmdroid

I Can't get Real Path between two points , I got a direct line between them, here is my sample code, 
I put that code under onCreate method , also I tried to handle it by runnable but without getting a worth result , just a direct line between two points

```
GeoPoint startPoint = new GeoPoint(48.2,-1.88) ; 
RoadManager roadManager = new OSRMRoadManager();
ArrayList waypoints = new ArrayList(); 
waypoints.add(startPoint); GeoPoint endPoint = new GeoPoint(48.4, -1.9); 
waypoints.add(endPoint);
Road road = roadManager.getRoad(waypoints);
Polyline roadOverlay = RoadManager.buildRoadOverlay(road, this);
map.getOverlays().add(roadOverlay);
map.invalidate();
```

Any advice, suggestions or help ?

Comment: Likely a duplicate with this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21213224/roadmanager-for-osmdroid-error/21894178#21894178

Comment: @MKer I checked the link , the version of android which I used is API 22 , then I got the following URL in logcat , it seems that I got a response without drawing the real path, please check and advise ?http://router.project-osrm.org/viaroute?&loc=48.129999999999995,-1.63&loc=48.099999999999994,-1.6099999999999999&instructions=true&alt=false

Comment: @MKer I got in mStatus = 200 , also when I set log.i inside mStatus != ok . I got the log in the logcat , so what is the problem related to and how can i solved it even if i got the road, I mentioned the url in the previous comment . Can you help , I need this .... Many thanks

Comment: 1) Please provide the relevant section of your logcat. 2) Which version of OSMBonusPack are you using? 3) You are using API 22: did you read this: https://github.com/MKergall/osmbonuspack/wiki/Tutorial_0#important-note-about-network-calls ?

Comment: am using 4.5, you mean that you need a copy of logcat behind that url ?

Comment: Here is the log :: 04-15 16:58:24.317 16801-16801/com.android.application.osm D/BONUSPACK: OSRMRoadManager.getRoad:http://router.project-osrm.org/viaroute?&loc=48.129999999999995,-1.63&loc=48.12,-1.5&instructions=true&alt=false
04-15 16:58:24.331 16801-16801/com.android.application.osm W/System.err:     at org.osmdroid.bonuspack.routing.OSRMRoadManager.getRoad(OSRMRoadManager.java:205)
04-15 16:58:24.331 16801-16801/com.android.application.osm E/BONUSPACK: OSRMRoadManager::getRoad: request failed.

Comment: I got this message many times : OSRMRoadManager::getRoad: request failed.